# Haddock: generating documentation for multiple re-exported modules through the same identifier

Tags: haskell, haddock

Is it possible to have haddock generating documentation for modules that are re-exported with an aliased identifier?

I have the following two modules:

Module `A`:

```
module A where

data A = A
```

Module `B`:

```
module B where

data B = B
```

Then if I re-export the `A` and `B` through a third module `Lib` as follows:

```
module Lib
    ( someFunc
    , module A
    , module B
    ) where

import           A
import           B
```

Haddock generates documentation for `A` and `B`. However, if I change the code of `Lib` to this:

```
module Lib
    ( someFunc
    , module X
    ) where

import           A as X
import           B as X
```

While causes `Lib` to export the definitions of `A` and `B`, haddock will complain about it not being able to find the documentation for `X`:

```
Warning: Lib: Could not find documentation for exported module: X
```

Is there a way to generate documentation for `A` and `B` with an alias?

Comment: http://trac.haskell.org/haddock/ticket/225

Comment: I'll follow that ticket then. Thanks!

Comment: The bug above seems to be updated, a more recent version can be found here: https://github.com/haskell/haddock/issues/584, and here https://github.com/haskell/haddock/issues/563.